# python regex optional match hyphen

Tags: python, regex

How can I write the Regular expressions to accept hyphen but not be mandatory.

Since the folder name can have hyphen in it and sometimes not.

WHen I tried this:

```
r'^(?P<event_folder_name>[\w-]+)/$/result
```

It will accept only with hyphen

If I try like this:

```
r'^(?P<event_folder_name>\w+)
```

it wont accept it if hyphen is included.

**How can I make it that it accept both case.**

Thanks.

Comment: This really just required a little more effort.. Python.org has a GREAT tutorial explaining regex that I would take a few hours and make sure you understand.  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html .. I would also recommend bookmarking this: http://www.pythonregex.com/ .. There are plenty of great web-based regex tools that will help show you exactly how your regex are matching and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the $ sign matches the end of the string. Anything after it in the regular expression will be discarded.

Second, your first rule seems ok to me (except the $ in the middle of the expression of course). `[\w-]+` means any alphanumeric character (`\w`) or hyphen (`-`) one or more times (`[]+`).